# Git apply patch only if above specific revision

Tags: git, shell

I have a git repo (say RepoA) cloned say at specific revision (say RevX).
And I have another repository (say RepoB) which has a "git patch" file (say Patch1) for the code in RepoA at RevX.

Now someone updated the code in RepoA to new revision (say RevY) in such a manner that my patch file now fails.
So I have created a new patch file (say Patch2) for RevY.

My Query: In a shell script, I want to apply Patch1 if the local copy of RepoA is before RevY and apply Patch2 if the local copy of RepoA is after RevY.

How can this be done?

EDIT : There can be multiple revisions between RevX and RevY.. For example:
RevX

RevX+1

RevX+2

...

RevX+n

RevY

RevY+1

Answer (score 0):

You can use `git rev-parse HEAD` to determine the current revision and then decide to apply Patch1 or Patch2.

Comment: How can that be used for a range? like how can I know if current one is "before" or "after" RevY?

Comment: Did you try to parse git rev-list ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `git log`

```
git log --pretty=oneline HEAD~10..HEAD
```

This will print the hash and commit message of 10 most recent commits, you can change the number above to print more. Then you can search the list for `RevX` and `RevY`.

But I would suggest another workflow:

```
Checkout the specific `Rev` -> Apply the patch -> Commit -> Merge with the newest commit
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a direct solution to the question you asked: `git merge-base --is-ancestor A B` tests whether commit-ID *`A`* is an ancestor of commit-ID *`B`*, so you can simply test whether the current commit is an ancestor of the commit known to change the required patch.

The problem with this method is that it tests just what it says it tests: that commit *`A`* is an ancestor of specific commit *`B`*, not "of some commit that makes the *same change as* commit *`B`*".  If someone cherry-picks commit *`B`*, they get the same change but with a new (different) commit-ID.  The old patch will fail, and the new one will be required instead, but their branch will not contain commit *`B`* itself, just something *equivalent*.

If that situation is not important to you, you can use the `merge-base --is-ancestor` test.  Otherwise I would advise a different strategy, such as inspecting the code-to-be-patched for various signatures (e.g., "if the code near function call `f()` looks like Version A, use Patch A; if it looks like B, use Patch B; if it looks like C or D, use PatchCD; if it looks like fixed version E, do nothing; otherwise complain that we don't know how to patch this version").